# Store arrays of Strings using relationship SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, arrays, string, sqlalchemy, relationship

I need to store objects in a relational database, and some of these objects' attributes are arrays of Strings.
The problem is I'm using MariaDB which does not support the ARRAY type. Currently I'm using the JSON parsing "trick" to store arrays as a string that I parse, but since I need to specify a max String length, this trick does not work for every array if they exceed a certain size.

For arrays of custom objects I'm using relationship patterns provided by SQLAlchemy, but I do not manage to do the same with strings. There always seems to need an object primary key to store the one to many relationship in another table, but in the case of storing a String, I do not have that, and I do not really want to put my String into a custom object, just to have a key for my relationship.

What I would like to have is store something like that

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, id, array_of_str):
        self.id = id
        self.array_of_str = array_of_str
```

like this:

```
# Table that stores the MyObject instances
my_objects_table = Table(
    'my_object', metadata,
    Column('id', String(50), primary_key=True)
)

# Table that stores all the strings, linked to the MyObject instances
my_objects_arrays_of_strings_table = Table(
    'my_object_id', metadata,
    Column('my_object_id', String(50), ForeignKey('my_object.id')),
    Column('str_value', String(100))
)

mapper(
    MyObject, my_objects_table,
    properties={
        'array_of_str': relationship(
            # Problematic part
            # How to specify that the values to get are in the 'str_value'
            # column and that they should be associated with a specific object
            # identified by its ID.
        )
    }
```

I hope my problem is clear enough. Actually this questions is the same for all other primitive types.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: *"since I need to specify a max String length, this trick does not work for every array if they exceed a certain size"* - SQLAlchemy's "mysql" dialect can work with the `LONGTEXT` data type which allows for a maximum of 4 GiB. Would that not be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: I know I can always increase the size for a column.. I might never reach this limit of 4 GiB, but I'm thinking there could be a cleaner way. What if I want to do simple SQL operations on my table ? I cannot because my data is encoded...

Comment: *"What if I want to do simple SQL operations on my table ?"* - In that case you might consider using a JSON column type if it is available in your particular environment. (I know that it is available in recent versions of MySQL; not sure about MariaDB but I think it's likely.)